# Bind `meteor.method` type bindings to a plain object

Tags: javascript, meteor

This might sound strange, but I have a class. When I create the class, I want to generate a lot of meteor methods.

```
Robot = class RobotServer extends RobotBase {
  // ... not terribly important
  // want to make this run as if it were a meteor method
  send(command) {
    if (Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId, 'operator', this._id)) {
      this._sockets.get('commands').write(`${command}\r`);
    }
  }
}
```

I want to expose this as if it were a meteor method. That is to say, on my client, I can do something like:

```
Baymax = new Robot();
Baymax.send('message "I am Baymax, your personal health care companion"', function (err, result) {
  console.log('command successfully sent.')
});
```

Is this possible within meteor?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish? Where would those instances "live"? Why many methods instead of a single one that will interpret the command? And wouldn't simply including a method in the `Robot.prototype.send()` method do the trick?

Comment: I want to bind things like `this.userId`, `this.connection`, and all of those instances that are bound to a `Meteor.method` to these functions.